# C - Incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[LENGTH]' from type 'char *'

Tags: c

I want to assign a struct value (that can be max 50 characters) from standard input but am getting the error:

> Incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[50]' from type 'char
>   *'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 50

struct msgbuf {
 char mtext[MAX_LEN];
};


int main (int argc, char *argv)
{
    struct msgbuf m;
    char in[MAX_LEN];

    scanf ("%s", in);
    m.mtext = in;

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to cast `in` to a `char*`?

Comment: @mstbaum Since it makes no difference I edited it out

Comment: you can't assign an array to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have no the copy  assignment operator. You have to copy arrays element by element. You can use standard function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>` that to copy strings. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( m.mtext, in );
```